# How do I force the image meta tag that I use?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I designed an image fitting the 1200 * 627 px for the `meta` tag of my HTML page. Linkedin still uses [other alternative images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8zxP.png) from my site in posts. How can I force using only the defined image?

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/meta.png" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200px">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="627px">
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Comment: Added it, thanks Rob. I'm new here and thought that was sufficient. Appreciate your input.